# Multiple javascript counters on the same page

Tags: javascript, counter

I'm hosting tournaments throughout the year, and have the price increasing each day. Code works, but I'm not sure which elements to adjust to be able to display multiple prices adjusting simultaneously. I tried changing "rate" to "rate1" etc, but that wasn't enough... So I'm guessing variables within should be adjusted as well. Any help is appreciated. The page I'm working on is here: http://limitlesshoops.com/jamball.html -- The snippet below is what I'm currently focused on. Thanks.

```
    <div class="eventbox mlk activebox"><img src="https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/jammlk.gif" class="holidayback">
    <span class="eventlabel tourney">MLK DAY SHOWCASE</span><br><div class="numberfont eventdetails">
    January 17-18, 2022<br>
    Grades: 1st-8th<br>
    Current Price: <div class="rate" style="display: inline; font-weight:bold;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const days = (date) => Math.ceil(date.getTime() / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
const DEADLINE = days(new Date("2022-01-10"));
const START = days(new Date("2021-10-01"));
const TODAY = days(new Date());
const res = Math.round(400 - 300 * ((DEADLINE - TODAY) / (DEADLINE - START)));
console.log(res);
document.querySelector('.rate').append(`$${res}`)
</script>
<br>
</div>
<table class="buttontable"><tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="eventlink"><div class="eventbutton">Brackets</div></a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="eventlink"><div class="eventbutton">Register</div></a></td></tr></table> 
</div>



<div class="eventbox "><img src="https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/jamabe.png" class="holidayback">
    <span class="eventlabel">PREZ DAY CHALLENGE</span><br><div class="numberfont eventdetails">
    February 17-18, 2022<br>
    Grades: 1st-8th<br>
    Current Price: <div class="rate" style="display: inline; font-weight:bold;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const days = (date) => Math.ceil(date.getTime() / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
const DEADLINE = days(new Date("2022-02-10"));
const START = days(new Date("2021-10-01"));
const TODAY = days(new Date());
const res = Math.round(400 - 300 * ((DEADLINE - TODAY) / (DEADLINE - START)));
console.log(res);
document.querySelector('.rate').append(`$${res}`)
</script>
<br>
</div>
<table class="buttontable"><tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="eventlink"><div class="eventbutton">Brackets</div></a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="eventlink"><div class="eventbutton">Register</div></a></td></tr></table> 
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use different variable names for each of them. Or use IIFEs to put each variable in a different scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a loop to generate these HTML elements as they have the same structure. It is easier to maintain and far more less code.

Below is my solution:

```
<div id="eventboxcontainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = [
    {
        "title" : "MLK DAY SHOWCASE",
        "img" : "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/jammlk.gif",
        "dateRange" : "January 17-18, 2022",
        "grades" : "1st-8th",
        "deadline" : "2022-01-10",
        "start" : "2021-10-01"
    },
    {
        "title" : "PREZ DAY CHALLENGE",
        "img" : "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/jamabe.png",
        "dateRange" : "February 17-18, 2022",
        "grades" : "1st-8th",
        "deadline" : "2022-02-10",
        "start" : "2021-10-01"
    }
    ];

    

    var days = (date) => Math.ceil(date.getTime() / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var TODAY = days(new Date());

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        var html = "";

        var DEADLINE = days(new Date(data[i].deadline));
        var START = days(new Date(data[i].start));

        var rate = Math.round(400 - 300 * ((DEADLINE - TODAY) / (DEADLINE - START)));

        html = '<div class="eventbox mlk activebox"><img src="' + data[i].img + '" class="holidayback">'+
               '<span class="eventlabel tourney">' + data[i].title + '</span><br><div class="numberfont eventdetails">'+
               data[i].dateRange + '<br>'+
               data[i].grades + '<br>'+
               'Current Price: <div class="rate" style="display: inline; font-weight:bold;">' + rate + '</div>'+
               '<br>'+
               '</div>'+
               '<table class="buttontable"><tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="eventlink">'+
               '<div class="eventbutton">Brackets</div></a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="eventlink">'+
               '<div class="eventbutton">Register</div></a></td></tr></table> </div>';

        // you need jQuery for this
        //$("#eventboxcontainer").append(html);

        // pure Javascript
        var element = document.querySelector("#eventboxcontainer");
        element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);


    }

</script>
```

Comment: That's unreal. It works, but I need to look over it a ton to actually learn from it. But right now, to me, it's magic... So thank you for your wizardry :-)

Comment: I've successfully added the loop you've created, but I can't get it to work twice on the same page. I'd like for the 3v3 column to have the same functionality: http://limitlesshoops.com/jamball.html --- Thanks for any help you're able to provide.

Comment: does 3v3 column have the same data?

Comment: The same data, except a different formula for tabulating the current and future prices. When I added it with the same container class name, it put the info below. When I changed that name, it just came up as blank. I inspected it with chrome, but that gave no clues. So weird how you got it to follow the HTML data like that

Comment: Got it! Can't believe it took this much time for me to figure it out. Javascript IDs, classes and variables can not start with a number. They should start with a letter or underscore(_). change your 3v3container to container3v3 and it should be all good.

Comment: That was exactly the issue, but I'd like to one-up you. I figured out that number & class name thing 3 weeks ago in regard to a separate issue I was having, and I completely forgot about it. This stuff is really hard. Thank you so much for the assistance.